# I don't sometimes drink tea

Tags: adverbs

Why don't native speakers use "sometimes" between verbs?

"I don't sometimes drink tea."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Sometimes" obviously means *some* times, so it wouldn't make sense to use that negatively the way your example suggests. When used this way as an adverb of frequency, 'sometimes' sits in the middle between *never* and *always*, so you wouldn't just negate it - you'd use a better adverb.

"Some" can by default mean 'not all'. For example, "I go to the gym on some days" would mean you do not go every day. Likewise, we use 'sometimes' in connection with things that *do* occur, but not *very* often, so there is also no need to use it negatively to refer to the occasions when something doesn't occur.

Saying "I sometimes drink tea" means you *do* drink it, but *not all the time*. If you wanted to use a negative to mean the same thing, you could also say "I *don't often* drink tea". Of course, if you don't drink it at all you would simply say "I don't drink tea" or "I *never* drink tea" - there is no need to use an adverb of frequency with something that never happens.

However, you *could* use 'sometimes' in a negative sense if the thing you were proposing was an alternative to the norm. For example, if you *mostly* drank tea, but *occasionally* drank coffee instead, you might say "sometimes I don't drink tea".

Comment: Alternatively though, in response to "You drink tea _all_ the time", I could say "Sometimes I don't drink tea", "I don't drink somtimes" or "I sometimes don't drink tea". I _thought_ that  the OP was questioning why the 'last place' I could potentially drop in the word sometimes in that sentence (i.e. between don't & drink) isn't idiomatic.

Comment: @anotherdave that's a good point, that's more for highlighting 'something' which is an alternative to the norm. To say "sometimes I don't drink tea" it would have to be tacit that you do *usually* drink it.

Comment: @Astralbee, So the only case when "sometimes" isn't used negatively is when it is between verbs? I don't understand one thing. All sentences written by anotherdave are correct but they are negative and  "sometimes" is still used in them.

Comment: @AntoniaA Forget the "between verbs" rule, that doesn't exist. As I explained, you could say "I don't *often* drink tea" and that is just another adverb of frequency. The meaning of 'sometimes' as an adverb of frequency specifically means 'some, but not all', and that is just something which cannot be negated. If something isn't occasional, then it is either more, or less frequent. You would just use a different adverb.

Comment: @Astralbee, I understand that it doesn't exist.  What I don't understand is that when you said regarding my original sentence  "Sometimes" obviously means some times, so it wouldn't make sense to use that negatively the way your example suggests". Why doesn't it make sense in my original sentence which is a negative sentence, but makes sense in these sentences:   "Sometimes I don't drink tea", "I don't drink somtimes" or "I sometimes don't drink tea" as anotherdave suggested they are all correct.

Comment: @AntoniaA I've been updating my answer to accommodate the suggestion from anotherdave and also in response to your questions, I hope its clear now. "Sometimes I don't drink tea" would be a useless statement on its own unless you added what you DO on the occasions when you don't drink tea (ie you drink coffee instead). Placing 'sometimes' where you did in your example is what is problematic because you're negating the action, not the drink.

Comment: @Astralbee, thank you so much. You said "Placing 'sometimes' where you did in your example is what is problematic because you're negating the action, not the drink." You are talking about the original sentence, aren't you?

Comment: @Astralbee, But in these sentences we are negating the drink "Sometimes I don't drink tea", "I don't drink somtimes" or "I sometimes don't drink tea" and that's why they work. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

It's not really "between verbs" in this case because "don't drink" is the negative form of "to drink". Here the construction is negative and *sometimes*
is sort of negative in the sense that it's less of something. For example, you generally can't use *rarely* or *hardly* to split the negative construction either.

I.e "I don't rarely drink tea" doesn't really work.

You can use it to split other verb constructions/tenses though like "You will sometimes have to go away" makes perfect sense or "He likes to sometimes dance in the rain"

Comment: @Astralbee, but if I don't use it between the verbs are other positions correct? Or because it's not because of the position but of the logic, are these sentences also wrong? 1. "Sometimes I don't drink tea/read." 2. "I sometimes don't drink tea/ read." 3. "I don't read/drink tea sometimes.

Comment: @AntoniaA All three are correct and make perfect sense (and have the same meaning)

Comment: then I don't understand why a native speaker said the examples below are wrong. 
'No, I sometimes don't drink tea.':thumbsdown:
'No, I don't drink tea sometimes.':thumbsdown:

Comment: @AntoniaA  As a native speaker myself I can confidently say that I say sentences like those ALL the time. For example "I sometimes just don't get what is happening" or "I don't care about him sometimes". I should add, this placement of sometimes is not a big mistake, if you keep on talking hardly anyone will notice because native speakers make these kinds of slip-ups all the time.

Comment: I would expect "Sometimes I don't X" to be followed by a statement of what you do instead on those occasions. "Sometimes I don't drink tea, but make a pot of coffee instead." It sounds odd on its own; "I don't always drink tea" would be more natural.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Is it just this sentence or the following  sentences too that are odd on their own?  "Sometimes I don't drink tea", "I don't drink somtimes" or "I sometimes don't drink tea".

Comment: All of them seem to me to require "... but I do X instead".

Comment: I might add that "Sometimes I don't drink tea" would be permissible so long as there's some contrast somewhere, but "I don't sometimes drink tea" could only work tightly bound to a contrasting parallel structure--say, in the sentence "I don't sometimes drink tea, I always drink tea!"--and even then only informally.